Spark dataset aggregation with condition

I have the dataset in spark as in picture , I want to aggregate Units and Dollars of this dataset , but skip the row where Month is null during my aggregation . How can I do this in spark java.
My result should be as below (the units for empty month is incorrect)

My current code for aggregation:
input.rollup(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(allSelectedCols).seq())
                .agg(ratingCols.get(0),
                        JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(ratingCols.subList(1, ratingCols.size()).iterator())
                                .asScala().toSeq())
                .sort(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(orderedCols).seq());

allSelectedCols=are the headers of the screenshot
ratingCols=
ratingCols.add(expr("sum(Units)").as("Units"));
    ratingCols.add(
            expr("CAST(ROUND(SUM(CAST(Dollars AS DOUBLE)),3)  as decimal(36,3))").as("Dollars"));


Also, can you share the code you are using for aggregating ?

You can use 'if' in your sum expression with a default value for the null case:
ratingCols.add(expr("sum(if(isnull(Month), 0.0, Units))").as("Units"));

